# Proving existence of inverse function using the rule of differentiating inverse functions.

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

I am working from a textbook that gives us that

> The derivative of the inverse function is  $$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \large{\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}}.\qquad (*)$$

$$$$
Now I am stuck on part $(a)$ of the following question:

> A function is defined by $\ f(x) =x^3 + 3x + 2.$
>
> $(a)$ By considering $f'(x),\ $ prove that $\ f(x)\ $ has an inverse function.
>
> $(b)\ $ Find the gradient of the graph of $y=f^{-1}(x)$ at the point where $x=2.$

$$$$
For $(b),\ f(x) = 2\ \iff x=0\ $. Therefore, the gradient of the graph of $y=f^{-1}(x)$ at the point where $\ x=2\ $ is equal to $\ \large{\frac{1}{f'(0)}} = \frac{1}{3}.$

But I'm simply a bit confused unsure on what it wants for part $(a)$... The derivative of the inverse function is $\ \large{\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2+1} },\ $ but this does not say that, for example, the derivative of the inverse function $\ y=f^{-1}(x)\ $ at the point $\ x=3\ $ is $\ \large{\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3^2+1} },\ $ which it isn't. This means I find $(*)$ confusing as to what it is saying exactly, and like I say, I'm confused about this and not sure how to tackle part $(a)$. Please can someone clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a)\quad f'(x) =3(x^2 +1)\geq3>0\ $ for all $\ x.\ $ Therefore $\ f(x)\ $ is strictly increasing, and therefore one-to-one. Since a one-to-one function has an inverse, $\ f(x)\ $ has an inverse, i.e. $\ f^{-1}(x)\ $ exists.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative of an inverse can be written more clearly as
$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))},$$
and part $(a)$ can be shown straightforwardly using the inverse function theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

(a) Let g(.) be the inverse function of f(.)

```
f'(x) =  3(x^2 + 1) > 0 for all x.

f is strictly increasing, therefore, it is one to one.

Hence its inverse g: R-->R, defined by g(x) = $f^{-1}(x)$

and g'(f(x)) = 1/f'(x)

  By definition g(f(x)) = x.

  Differentiating wrt x, by chain rule of differentiation,  we have

  g'(f(x))f'(x)= 1 or 

  g'(f(x)) = 1/f'(x).
```

(b)   g'(f(2)) = $\frac{1} {3(2^2 + 1)}$ = $\frac{1} {15}$

Comment: Your first line is wrong. $\ f'(x)\neq  \frac{3}{x^2 + 1}.\ $ Please amend this.

Comment: And I don't understand how you got your answer for part $(b)$, but I'm fairly sure you're wrong, and I think the answer is $\ \frac{1}{3},\ $ as this is what is says in the back of the book, and it makes sense to me. However, your argument for the existence of the inverse function makes sense.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson Thanks for pointing out my error in f'(x). I have made a correction. The correct f'(x) is f'(x) = 3($x^2$ + 1).

Comment: @Adam Rubinson The answer for part (b) is 1/15 as shown.

Comment: No, I'm fairly sure it's $\ \frac{1}{3}.\ $ Basically, the coordinate $\ (0,2)\ $ lies on the graph of $\ f,\ $ and the gradient of $\ f\ $ at this point is $\ 3.\ $ This corresponds to the coordinate $\ (2,0)\ $ on the graph of $\ f^{-1}.\ $ And so the gradient of $\ f^{-1}\ $ at this point must be $\ \frac{1}{3},\ $ due to the inverse function $\ f^{-1}\ $ being a reflection of $\ f\ $ in the line $\ y=x.$